# Oracle Apex email validation

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have an item to enter the email ids `item_email`

I need to give validation for email id item `item_email` that the email id should not exists already in table.

So I have to create email validation please help me to proceed on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a `Validation` (`Processing` tab) with type `No Rows Returned`, and put the following to the validation query:

```
select 1
  from table_with_emails
 where email_column = :P_EMAIL_ITEM
```

**UPD**
To check email: create a new validation (it is easier than add two checks in one) with type `PL/SQL Expression`, and add the following:

```
regexp_like (:P_EMAIL_ITEM, '^[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9.]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$')
```

Creating a new validation also allows you to define two different error messages: when email is already exists and when it has wrong format.

Comment: Hello Is there is any way to pass only one email id in email field. For Ex: In item_email it should accept only one email id

Comment: For example, you can count how much symbols `@` you have in the string. It should be only one. Or you can try to find a solution to validate email format. I think there are plenty of them here. Two or more emails will not pass this validation.

Comment: Hello Its an text field, how can i count the @ for that text field and where i have to do it, could you please expand the answer little more, Thanks

Comment: @Abinnaya Updated.

Comment: That format validation is too strict. Actually adhering to [the RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822) is almost never done, as it is impractically permissive, yet this errs too far on the side of strict. A [quick read](https://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx/) to help get some perspective.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, consider creating UNIQUE INDEX on e-mail column. Apex validation would do the job, but won't prevent another ways of inserting data.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a unique constraint in the oracle db for the email column. The validation using the regular expression with oracle apex.